# calls to constexpr vs inline functions compile to different assembly with optimization disabled

Tags: c++, c++11, assembly, inline, constexpr

I came across this awesome online Compiler Explorer https://godbolt.org/
which shows assembly version of your code.
I was also reading about new C++ 11 features and found out about constexpr.

take a look at square function below :

```
constexpr int square(int num) {
    return num * num;
}

int main()
{
    int result = square(2);
    return 0;
}
```

and following assembly code generated for two versions (constexpr and inline)

CONSTEXPR https://godbolt.org/z/c69qrevET

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 4   ; compile time constant 4 = 2*2
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

INLINE https://godbolt.org/z/czaKT8fhY

```
square(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     edi, 2
        call    square(int)
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

I read everywhere that functions like this can be inlined but why there's a function call code in asm version? According to inline definition it should be avoided right?

Answer (score 2):

`constexpr` functions are not guaranteed to be executed at compile-time unless they're used in a context where a *constant expression* is required. Change your code to

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int result = square(2);
    return 0;
}
```

and you'll see a difference, because `constexpr` variables require to be initialized with a *constant expression*.

Note that optimization level also matters.

Comment: Good to know that. Thank you.

Comment: @Ankitsinghkushwah: if this answers your question please click the green checkmark to mark it as answered.

Comment: The `constexpr` function call already *is* evaluated at compile time by GCC, it's the "inline" function that isn't.  (With optimization disabled).  Also, the "as if" rule allows the compiler to eval at runtime if it wants to.  Only cases like `int foo[square(2)];` as a struct member or at global scope will give GCC no option, even for a really complex `constexpr` function that it might otherwise (especially at low optimization level) choose to call at run time.  So the key part of your answer is that "optimization level matters".